# className returns undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of similar questions and answers, but after trying all solutions I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Here is my code

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('xclass1 xclass2 xclass3');
console.log(x);
x.className += ' class4';
console.log(x);
console.log(x.className);
```

Here is what shows up in the first console.log:

```
[a.xclass1.xclass2.xclass3]
```

It shows that it finds the right element

Here is what shows up in the second console.log:

```
[a.xclass1.xclass2.xclass3, className: "undefined class4"]
```

And the third one returns this:

```
undefined class4
```

Can anyone please explain why `className` returns `undefined`? I am completely lost here

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns *a collection of elements*, not just one, because you can have multiple elements with the same class.

Comment: take a look at classList

Comment: @AndrewLi Thank you very much! I just figured it out... `x[0].className += ' class4';` fixes it

Comment: If you are sure there will only be one such element on a certain page, you could just do var var x = document.getElementsByClassName('xclass1 xclass2 xclass3')[0]; and it should work

Comment: try to change this `x[0].className += ' class4';` to this `x[0].classList.push('class4');`  now with classList you have directly an array of classes, no need of concatenating strings with className

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below code snippet

return undefined because you trying to console class for array of object which include element not actual element.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('xclass1 xclass2 xclass3');
console.log(x);
x[0].className += ' class4';
console.log(x);
console.log(x[0].className);
```

```html
<div class="xclass1 xclass2 xclass3"></div>
```